# Catch event on user control

Tags: events, user-controls

On windows form, I have an UserControl (UC).
In this UC, there is a WebBrowser control which does not have the DragDrop event.

How can I catch the DragDrop on my UC's area?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can point to the right directions:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984430(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Thanks, my application can drag and drop outside of WebBrowser control. I think, I have an issue with event handling.

Comment: Without more details I can´t help I'm afraid.